# Sass pattern for traversing up the tree

Tags: css, sass, css-selectors

I have the following SASS structure

```
 .entry {
        //some styles here 
        .banner {
            border:4px solid red;
                .position {
                    display: inline-block;
                }
        }
    }
```

And in html

```
<div class="entry">
    <div class="banner>
        <div class="position"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now I want to change the style of .banner and .position when an extra class is added to the entry.

```
<div class="entry team1">
        <div class="banner>
            <div class="position"></div>
        </div>
</div>
```

This is a problem I have encountered lots of times and have never found a clean way to do it, the & operator or the @extend could be options but ideally I would like to group all the styles which have the same class.

Any suggestion on how I could write this pattern as efficiently as possible would be appreciated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I would suggest something like that:

```
.entry {
    .banner { /* defaults */ }


    &.team1 {
        .banner { 
            /* changes */ 
            .position { /*changes */}
        }
    }

}
```

As far as I know, it is not possible to »traverse up the tree« in css, so it wont in scss either.

Another thing that comes to my mind is the [@at-root](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#at-root) what moves the rule to the root of the generated css. But all in all this will result in a »global« class definition, so I guess that is not what you want.

Comment: Hi, I have used both these techniques, the one posted here is probably the best.